# Team Foundation Service build versioning

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, versioning, azure-devops

I want to add the Changeset and the BuildNr into my version number. In example:
`4.5. _Changeset_ . _BuildNr_`

I have found some solutions for doing it through console and that exists some extensions to add to you an on-premises Team Foundation Server.

But I'm using the hosted [Team Foundation *Service*](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) so I can't add any extension, with **Visual Studio 2012 Pro** and I can't find any solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need to add extensions to the tfs through console (even though this is possible). Working with extensions in TFS 2012, just like the Team Foundation Service works exactly like in TFS 2010. You have to checkin the extension assembly and customize your build templates. This should be also possible with VS 2012 Professional (at least I remember, I did this with VS 2010 Pro).

Take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/e8ba2e76-eb58-4811-a12c-0cdc1f9ec3cd) community post. Also you might read [this blog post](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx) that handles customization of Team Build.

Last but not least you will find a complete solution [on CodePlex](http://versionedtfsbuild.codeplex.com/). You can completely set it up from Visual Studio's integrated Team Explorer.

Comment: How to set custom assembly path on the cloud: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/build/hosted-build-controller-in-vs/

Comment: So much information _des-informed_ me. Thanks for focusing me!